# Running directx SDK samples on a Windows Mobile 6.1 device

Tags: deployment, windows-mobile, directx, sample

I tried to run the directx samples from ..\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\PocketPC\CPP\win32\directx\d3dm\tutorials on a Samsung Omnia and on the emulator and it doesn't work because of a deployment error.
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and have installed Windows Mobile SDK Standard and Professional refresh.
The device is correctly plugged in and set up for active sync (I know this because other samples work, also a creating Win32 smart device application and running it works).
When I try to run a directx sample application it compiles without errors but the message:

" There were deployment errors, Continue? Yes/No"   appears

If I manually copy the application from the debug folder to the device and run it from there, it works.

The same deployment error message appears if I try it on an emulator. Other applications are deploying successfully.

Is there any way to make the deployment work? Maybe there is an obscure option I need to set...

What I do is:
Connect the Mobile device to the PC,
Open Visual Studio 2008,
Open a directx sample project,
Click Run (in Debug or Release mode).

Comment: Usually when the "there were deploy..." message appears you can see elaborated log in the output window. Can you see what the deployment error was and update the question?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put that there:

1>------ Deploy started: Project: tut01_createdevice, Configuration: Debug Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I) ------
1>The system cannot find the file specified.
1>
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Unfortunately I don't know the deployment mechanism and I don't know what file it's talking about. I'll do more digging into this.

Comment: In "Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Deployment" then "General->Additional files" the following was there   msvcr80.dll|$(BINDIR)\$(INSTRUCTIONSET)\|%CSIDL_WINDOWS%|0;   I removed the whole text and retried. The deployment is now working. I only tried it for the first directx sample

Comment: Can anyone tell me what do $(BINDIR) and $(INSTRUCTIONSET) macros expand to? I can't seam to find this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the deployment is that the file `msvcr80.dll` could not be found.
It was specified at the deployment options as an additional file `"Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Deployment"` then `"General->Additional files"`
with the paths `msvcr80.dll|$(BINDIR)\$(INSTRUCTIONSET)\|%CSIDL_WINDOWS%|0;`
Removing it makes the deployment successful. I have only tested this on a Windows Mobile 6.1 device and with the D3DM reference driver on an WM6.1/WM6 emulator.

- What I haven't figured out is where does `$(BINDIR)\$(INSTRUCTIONSET)` point to.
- Also I don't know why msvcr80.dll is in the addition files if it is not actually needed.
- Is there actually a msvcr80.dll compiled for Windows Mobile platform on an ARM cpu?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue after doing some low-level Sysinternals Debugging. It was trying to deploy NETCFv35.Messages.EN.cab to the device and in my case it was deleted for some reason. Re-installing .NET CF fixed the issue for me. Wish VS 2008 said what file was missing instead of a generic message. Hope this helps you too.